# haproxy - not reusing connections

Tags: haproxy, spray, keep-alive

I have a simple setup of 12 backend nodes (named `backend1` to `backend12`) behind `HAProxy` loadbalancer. If I understand the HAProxy default mode it should use http persistent connections - the problem is that in my case it seems to be not working properly based on what I am seeing using `netstat` tool.

Below is the snippet of `netstat` commands during simple loadtest execution against single backend node behind `HAProxy` (the other one is set to `MAINT` state). Loadbalancer IP inside my network is `10.254.1.39`

```
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp       88      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED on (0,19/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED on (0,21/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED on (0,19/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED on (0,21/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED on (0,21/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED on (0,22/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58272       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58188       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58424       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58492       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58620       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58643       ESTABLISHED on (0,19/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:58333       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

I can see that in time more connections are opened but old ones are kept and being reused. The same thing is if I put `backend1` to `MAINT` and enable only `backend2`

```
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39458       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED on (0,21/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39458       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED on (0,19/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39458       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39458       ESTABLISHED on (0,19/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39526       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:

tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39610       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39458       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39526       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ 
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39610       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39307       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39671       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39374       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39458       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:39526       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

The problem starts when I put both backends (and more) to `READY`.

Output from `backend1`:

```
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:59570       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:59574       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:59709       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:59706       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60209       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60212       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60212       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60826       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60813       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60831       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:60833       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:33498       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:33502       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:33500       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:33504       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:33507       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:34042       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:34039       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:34032       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:34036       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:34036       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
tcp       96      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:34045       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend1:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38181       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38150       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38167       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38163       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38179       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38170       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38130       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38172       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38139       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38176       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:35450       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38158       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38137       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38177       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38144       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38125       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38144       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.12:9091        10.254.1.39:38125       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

and from `backend2`

```
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:52464       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:52466       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:52628       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:52631       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53127       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53138       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53137       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53134       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53819       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53828       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53826       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:53821       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:54736       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:54728       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:54711       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:54738       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0    170 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:55342       ESTABLISHED on (0,18/0/0)
tcp        0    171 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:55344       ESTABLISHED on (0,20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:55340       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:55339       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
ubuntu@backend2:~$ netstat -tao | grep 39:
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59507       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59502       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59489       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59491       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59471       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59497       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59493       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59509       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59457       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59479       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59511       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59470       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59505       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59465       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59488       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.254.1.13:9091        10.254.1.39:59513       ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

Looking at the port numbers on loadbalancer side (`10.254.1.39`) they are changing which means that the connections are closed and reopened again. The question is - why? I assume that if connections are reused in single node case my backend server (which is `spray-can`: http://spray.io/) is capable of working with http persistent connections.

Here is my HAProxy configuration:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    maxconn 4096
    #chroot /usr/share/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    #debug
    #quiet

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 4096
    contimeout  5000
    clitimeout  50000
    srvtimeout  50000

frontend lb
    bind *:8080
    acl read_model_acl path_beg /check
    use_backend read_models if read_model_acl

backend read_models
   balance roundrobin
   server read-model1 10.254.1.12:9091 check 
   server read-model2 10.254.1.13:9091 check
   #more servers
```